# Checkbutton won't be set to variable value

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.x

I created a simple Python Tkinter gui and I can't manage to have Checkbutton initalize with the correct values, both are always unchecked,  no matter what I do, whereas the two prints in the code display :

```
('dryRunVar', 0)
('useGenreSubFolderVar', 1)
```

Tried whatever I could with BooleanVar also, and couldn't make it work

Strangely enough if I change instanciation of CheckButton() to ttk.CheckButton(), then both buttons are in 'gray' state

Even changing call to configuration values to constants 0 and 1 doesn't change anything, Buttons stay unchecked

Also try to tweak a little around Tk instanciation and mainloop, no success

```
#!/usr/lib/python2.7/
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *
import conf,ttk

class GUI():

    def __init__(self,window, configuration) :
        self.configuration = configuration
        self.window = window
        self.draw()

    def draw(self) :
        self.root = Frame(self.window,padx=15,pady=15,width=800,height=200)
        self.root.grid(column=0,row=0)        
        self.drawParametersFrame()

    def drawParametersFrame(self) :
        #Parameters frame
        self.parametersFrame = LabelFrame(self.root,text="Sorting Parameters",padx=15,pady=15)
        self.parametersFrame.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky="EW")
        dryRunVar = IntVar()
        dryRunVar.set(self.configuration['dryRun'])
        print("dryRunVar",dryRunVar.get())
        dryRunCheckButton = Checkbutton(self.parametersFrame,text="Dry Run", variable=dryRunVar, onvalue=1, offvalue = 0)
        dryRunCheckButton.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky="W")
        useGenreSubFolderVar = IntVar()
        useGenreSubFolderVar.set(self.configuration['genreSubFolders'])
        print("useGenreSubFolderVar",useGenreSubFolderVar.get())
        useGenreSubFolderCheckButton = Checkbutton(self.parametersFrame,text="Use genre subfolders", variable=useGenreSubFolderVar, onvalue=1, offvalue = 0)
        useGenreSubFolderCheckButton.grid(column=2,row=0,sticky="W")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    configuration = conf.loadConf(r"/home/thomas/code/perso/python/conf.conf")
    window = Tk()
    gui = GUI(window,configuration)
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `IntVar` an attribute of the class instead.

```
def drawParametersFrame(self) :
    ...
    self.dryRunVar = IntVar()
    self.dryRunVar.set(1)
    dryRunCheckButton = Checkbutton(self.parametersFrame,text="Dry Run", variable=self.dryRunVar, onvalue=1, offvalue = 0)
    ...
    self.useGenreSubFolderVar = IntVar()
    self.useGenreSubFolderVar.set(1)
    useGenreSubFolderCheckButton = Checkbutton(self.parametersFrame,text="Use genre subfolders", variable=self.useGenreSubFolderVar, onvalue=1, offvalue = 0)
    ...
```

Comment: Is it due to variable scope and local variable beeing destroyed ? Because in another frame, I use local StringVar for filling an Entry without any issue

Comment: It is likely to be garbage collected since there are no further reference to the IntVar created.